# Plotly - change the background color of the html page when doing fig.show()

Tags: python, plotly

Is there any way to change the background color of the page that pops up when I do `fig.show()`?
Currently it's just white. I can change the background color of the plot itself, but not the HTML body.

Comment: Could you please point it out with example?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `paper_bgcolor` as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])

fig.update_layout(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(192,192,192,255)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,204,204,255)'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]